# Javascript copy no repeat object data taht have same property from array

Tags: javascript

I have an arrry that has 100 object and it has same property `code`

```
Data = [ 

{yera:"2019", name:"saif", topic:"oil"},

{yera:"2018", name:"abc", topic: "oil"},

{yera:"2018", name:"jorj", topic:"energy"},

{yera:"2017", name:"tom", topic:"gas"},

{yera:"2016",name:"saif",topic:"electricity "},

{yera:"2014", name:"gour",topic:"oil"},
```

Comment: please add what you like to do, with some code, possibly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I want to copy all object  from Data in new array and new array store only unique object in Data  array some  duplicates object i.e i want to copy topic property of Data array  in new array  and new array should be stor unique topic value like new-array =["oil","energy ", "gas","electricity "] insted of   new-array =["oil","oil","oil","energy ", "gas","electricity "]  i.e  copy the vtopic value from Data array and ignore if topic value duplicate and copy next topic value from Data array and store new-array

Comment: new-array is a new array that  will be store  copyed value

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove duplicates from the array of objects based on a key of that object, the code below will achieve that.

```
var data = [

    {yera:"2019", name:"saif", topic:"oil"},

    {yera:"2018", name:"abc", topic: "oil"},

    {yera:"2018", name:"jorj", topic:"energy"},

    {yera:"2017", name:"tom", topic:"gas"},

    {yera:"2016",name:"saif",topic:"electricity "},

    {yera:"2014", name:"gour",topic:"oil"}
]


function getUniqueData(originalData, keyToCheckForUniqueness) {
    var store = {};
    var output = [];
    originalData.forEach(function (ob) {

        var val = ob[keyToCheckForUniqueness];

        if (!store[val]) {
            store[val] = [ob]; 
        } else {
            store[val].push(ob);
        }

    });
    // at this point your store contains all the repeating data based on that property value
    // console.log(store);

    // now emit single values from that store; 
    // this logic can be based on any criterion, I chose the first element of the array - it may change depending on the order of values in input
    Object.keys(store).forEach(function (key) {
        var uniqueValArray = store[key];
        var uniqueVal = uniqueValArray[0]; // take the first entry
        output.push(uniqueVal);
    });
    return output;
}

getUniqueData(data, "topic");
```

This will achieve what I think you want to figure out. A word of advice - Don't let people think when you ask them for help. Second, try writing the logic for yourself. Post your non-working solution and ask, where you made a mistake - rather than asking. Given your rep, welcome to SO. Hope you a great learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want unique values for a given property of the objects, you could map that value and take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for getting unique values.

```js
function getUnique(array, key) {
    return Array.from(new Set(array.map(({ [key]: v }) => v)));
}

var array = [{ year: "2019", name: "grace", topic: "oil" }, { year: "2018", name: "grace", topic: "oil" }, { year: "2018", name: "jane", topic: "energy" }, { year: "2017", name: "tom", topic: "gas" }, { year: "2016", name: "jane", topic: "electricity" }, { year: "2014", name: "gour", topic: "oil" }];

console.log(getUnique(array, 'year'));
console.log(getUnique(array, 'name'));
console.log(getUnique(array, 'topic'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: we can use this method in angular 6

Comment: i war try this method in angular 6 it is not working

Comment: sorry, i have no idea of angular.